# Getting error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another" while selecting table data

Tags: node.js, ms-access

I am getting an error while performing the select query like `select * from tablename`

`code:-2146825287
message:"Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."`

here is my code which I am using,

```
const connection = ADODB.open(
  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
    appRoot.path +
    "\\test.mdb"
);

const query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

connection
  .query(query)
  .then(data => {
    if (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
    callback();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    callback(null, error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as I checked the I have too many fields in a table. So that will throw an error. you have to select the only column which you want for your requirement in a query.

Like i.e.

`select column1, column2,etc. from tablename`